# Regex choose based on string format

Tags: regex, telegraf, re2

I have following formats of data:

```
CumulativeReport_cumulativeReportBins_CumulativeBinNetworksViews_totalSuccessfulHeartbeats_1
CumulativeReport_cumulativeReportBins_CumulativeBinNetworksViews_totalSuccessfulHeartbeats__1
```

I am using following regex:

```
^(.*)_(.*?_.*?)(_\d$|__\d$)
```

My requirement every time is to get CumulativeBinNetworksViews_totalSuccessfulHeartbeats. For first case its working fine but for second case its printing "totalSuccessfulHeartbeats_1". How to solve this.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
^(.*)_([^_]+_[^_]+)__?\d$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Uxrmum/1). *Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(.*)` - Group 1: any zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible
- `_` - an underscore
- `([^_]+_[^_]+)` - Group 2: one or more chars other than `_`, `_` and one or more chars other than `_`
- `__?` - one or two underscores
- `\d` - a digit
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: Thanks, it's working. On this...suppose I want to add two more formats present in the link https://regex101.com/r/ERqeGd/1. How can I get the same output for all 4 strings?

Comment: @Pratikdasbaghel `^(.*)_([^_]+_(?!_*\d$)[^_]+)(?:_(?:_?\d)?)?$` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/ERqeGd/2))

Comment: Hi. Ok so i am using telegraf which internally uses go regex. Above regex is not working for go, can you help me here. Thanks

Comment: @Pratikdasbaghel Then you will have to resort to workarounds. What about `^(.*)_([^_]+_[^_]*[^_\d])(?:_(?:_?\d)?)?$`? It will work if the last part of the match cannot end in a digit.